# how to return a typed tuple depending on which variable is not null?

Tags: c#, .net, functional-programming

**How can we implement pattern matching in order to return a tuple?**

**Currently method signature**

```
public static string Match(string nodeName, string nodeValue, string sourceParty, 
    string destinationParty, List<Translation> translations)
```

**Desired Method Signature**

```
public static (string, TypeOfMatch) Match(string nodeName, string nodeValue, 
    string sourceParty, string destinationParty, List<Translation> translations)
```

I have the following static method:

```
public static class Matcher
{
    public static string Match(string nodeName, string nodeValue, string sourceParty, 
        string destinationParty, List<Translation> translations)
    {
        //please excuse the pseudo code in these 3 lines
        var exactMatch = from.translations(where xyz).select.Take(1)
        var defaultMatch = from.translations.select(where abc).Take(1)
        var anySourceMatch = from.translations.select(where sss).Take(1)

        return exactMatch.FirstOrDefault() ??
            defaultMatch.FirstOrDefault() ??
            anySourceMatch.FirstOrDefault() ??
            nodeValue;
    }
}
```

I would like to know the `type` of match that was returned (whether it was exact/default/anySource).

Right now we are returning `string`, but perhaps the return should be a tuple such as `(TypeOfMatch, string)` where `TypeOfMatch` would be an enum such as:

```
public enum TypeOfMatch
{
    Exact, Default, AnySource
}
```

but then our return statement would be something like:

```
if (exactMatch.FirstOrDefault() != null)
    return (TypeOfMatch.Exact, exactMatch.First());

if (defaultMatch.FirstOrDefault() != null)
    return (TypeOfMatch.Default, defaultMatch.First());

// etc.
```

**Is there a more robust way of doing a `switch` on which of the variables were not null and then returning the pair `(TypeOfMatch, string)`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The challenge with your scenario is that value tuples are value types, and therefore cannot be combined using the [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator), `??`, which only works on nullable types. However, you could define an extension method to convert your value tuple into a *nullable* value type, which could then be subjected to `??`.

I am assuming that your `Translation` class has an implicit type conversion to `string`; otherwise, you need to call `ToString()` or read a string property when constructing your value tuples.

```
public static class Matcher
{
    public static (TypeOfMatch, string) Match(
        string nodeName, string nodeValue, string sourceParty,
        string destinationParty, List<Translation> translations)
    {
        return
            translations.Where(xyz).Select(t => (TypeOfMatch.Exact, t)).FirstOrNull() ??
            translations.Where(abc).Select(t => (TypeOfMatch.Default, t)).FirstOrNull() ??
            translations.Where(sss).Select(t => (TypeOfMatch.AnySource, t)).FirstOrNull() ??
            (TypeOfMatch.NodeValue, nodeValue);
    }
}

public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static T? FirstOrNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
        where T : struct
    {
        return source.Cast<T?>().FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: this looks like a brilliant solution, however, given the complexity of working with enums, perhaps it'd be better if instead of doing this `.Select(t => (TypeOfMatch.Exact, t.Value))` we could do something with a class rather than an enum like this: `.Select(t => (new TypeOfMatch("Exact"), t.Value))` ??

Comment: also `.Value` as you suggested is not an option

Comment: An enum would be the correct choice for this situation. I removed the `.Value` from my answer; you need to figure out how to convert the `Translation` to `string` based on your implementation of that type.

Comment: That link is returning a 500. Can you add the code or image to your question?

Comment: thanks dougles, the code compiles perfectly, havent tested yet, but i will need to be able to use the `string` representation of the `enum` values, like "Exact" and "Default" for a different purpose , so back to my question regarding making it a class rather than an enum, what do you think?

Comment: An enum is a better choice, since it provides guidance on the intended set of values. Someone getting a `TypeOfMatch` would know that it should typically be `Exact`, `Default`, or `AnySource`; whereas someone getting a `string` won't know anything about the intended values, unless you document them everywhere. If you want the string representations, you can just call `ToString()` on the enum value, which returns the enum member name as a string.

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''': I realized I had a bug in my extension method. Please use the corrected version above.